# I am including a phar file (goutte.phar) in my php application. When I try to hit the url I get Connection to the server was reset error

Tags: php, yii, phar, goutte

Is there any specific settings in `php.ini` that I need to change to allow the server to include the file?

```
require_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/unleashapi/protected/extensions/goutte.phar';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set in `php.ini` `auto_prepend_file`:

```
auto_prepend_file="/custom/path/unleashapi/protected/extensions/goutte.phar"
```

make sure Apache has access to that file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still not working mate. The same code works on the other machine. I am sure that I am missing some settings in php.ini but unable to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you server is using [suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/) (typically Debian and all Debian based distributions), you should add : `suhosin.executor.include.whitelist="phar"` to your php.ini